# Placing colors at 0.5*10^n intervals in a logarithmic, qualitative colorbar with a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, heatmap

I have been playing around with heatmaps as a way to display a lot of information in a visually impactful way. Using a linear colorbar scale I was able to compute the ticks and number of colors necessary to get a nice looking colorbar. However, when switching to a logarithmic colorbar, using `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm`, it becomes a bit trickier.

I am able to set meaningful max and min values based on the data set, and get the ticks at the intersection of the colors (see Fig 1).

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 1**. *Each color spans one order of magnitude*

The issue here is that the resolution is a bit low, and I would like to have twice as many colors. I can do this by multiplying by a factor of 2 when determining the number of colors, and the result is in Fig. 2.

[image: Figure 2]

**Figure 2**. *Each color spans the same area of the color bar, but spans different data ranges.*

However, due to the logarithmic scale, the two colors within one order of magnitude cover different ranges of data, and ideally I would like the intersection of the colors to be right at the 0.5*10^n mark.

Is there a relatively straightforward way of achieving this?

Snippet for reproducing the figures:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import math

data = [[0.0065513626834508175, 0.476779092353869, 0.021513472812344454, 0.37316274465007165, 0.11149228130361034, 0.05917159763313834, 0.07437156031533118, 0.1083790557474745, 0.0733214622394398, 0.17898426430010372], [0.18343815513625047, 0.9005827300017748, 0.629269079761209, 0.16754245678166085, 1.1749571183533365, 1.2228796844181362, 1.6064257028112423, 1.4021540337329765, 0.5813344506127501, 0.47729137146693623], [0.4192872117400517, 0.4414621225498852, 0.10218899585865526, 0.441702840606187, 0.03430531732417843, 0.05917159763313834, 0.3421091774505488, 0.216758111494949, 0.12045668796480033, 0.1416958759042417], [0.032756813417179606, 0.14126787921597278, 0.4141343516377186, 0.09138679460818258, 0.1543739279588273, 0.0657462195923697, 0.11899449650453413, 0.2235318024791601, 0.2435318024791601, 0.10440748750837972], [0.5634171907756903, 0.4591206074518771, 0.6131339751519469, 0.8300967176909628, 1.9125214408233189, 1.2294543063773862, 3.004611036739566, 0.8128429181060683, 0.6337069236409385, 1.1708553956297958], [0.27515723270441295, 0.4414621225498852, 0.1237024686709997, 0.0837712283908196, 0.13722126929673809, 0.039447731755425555, 0.20824036888293998, 0.34545824019507615, 0.04713522572536054, 0.2386456857334575]]
grid = pd.DataFrame(data)

exp_max = math.ceil(math.log10(grid.max().max()))
exp_min = math.floor(math.log10(grid.min().min()))

maxval = 10 ** exp_max
minval = 10 ** exp_min

n_colors = int(exp_max - exp_min) * 1
cmap = sns.color_palette('ch:start=2,rot=2,light=0.9,d=0.2', n_colors=n_colors)

norm = matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmax=maxval, vmin=minval)

kws = {
    'data': grid,
    'cmap': cmap,
    'square': True,
    'vmax': maxval,
    'linecolor': 'black',
    'lw': .3,
    'norm': norm
}

sns.heatmap(**kws)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: _"the two colors within one order of magnitude cover different ranges of data"_. Yes, this is true, but it does mean the relative size of each colour increases uniformly between all groups - i.e. each group is `10^0.5` larger than the last one, which seems to me to be more intuitive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with Seaborn, but if you're willing to fall back to Matplotlib, this should get your in the right direction.

The code below defines the levels manually. There is probably a way to get these automatically based on the min, max you already defined. But I could not find it right away, something along the lines of `np.geomspace` or `np.logspace` etc.

Currently it also loses the minor ticks on the colorbar. I'm not sure if that's important to you? They can probably be set by specifying different ticks, not only the (color) levels, and the changing the `minor_thresholds` to make it skip the minor ones.

The formatting of the `LogFormatter` is also slightly different, using the scientific notation (adding the "e"). I'm not sure if Matplotlib already has an available Ticker that uses the formatting from Seaborn. Maybe Seaborn has a custom function that works in combination with Matplotlib's `FuncFormatter`, I'm not that familiar with Seaborn unfortunately.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatter, IndexLocator

exp_max = math.ceil(math.log10(grid.max().max()))
exp_min = math.floor(math.log10(grid.min().min()))

maxval = 10 ** exp_max
minval = 10 ** exp_min

n_colors = int(exp_max - exp_min) * 1
cmap = sns.color_palette('ch:start=2,rot=2,light=0.9,d=0.2', n_colors=n_colors*2, as_cmap=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), constrained_layout=True, dpi=86, facecolor='w')

levels = [0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 5.0, 10.0]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

im = ax.imshow(grid, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

formatter = LogFormatter(5, labelOnlyBase=False, minor_thresholds=(np.inf, np.inf))
cb = fig.colorbar(im, ticks=levels, format=formatter, spacing="uniform", shrink=0.6)
cb.outline.set_visible(False)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(IndexLocator(base=1, offset=0))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(IndexLocator(base=1, offset=0))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(IndexLocator(base=1, offset=0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(IndexLocator(base=1, offset=0.5))

ax.grid(which='minor', color='k', linewidth=2)
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Maybe use `ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False, useMathText=True)` for the colorbar?